# DCP representation of a convex quotient of affine functions

Tags: convex-optimization, disciplined-convex-programming

I am trying to represent the following inequality:

$$\frac{x}{1-x} \leq y \qquad\mathrm{with}\qquad 0<x<1$$

The function on the left is convex (its second derivative is always positive over the domain $0<x<1$), meaning that the described set is convex. (Without the domain constraint, however, the domain is far from convex…) Drawing it gives the same conclusion:

[image: The set described by this inequality]

However, I cannot find a DCP representation of this set (even using nonstandard cones).

I can do it with a slight modification (replacing $x$ with $x^2$, two quad-over-lin constraints do the trick, CVX also accepts the constraint as $y\geq\frac{x^2}{z}$ and $z\leq 1-x^2$), but it is not describing the same set, and the difference is really significant in my case.

Comment: Look at section 4.3.2 "Linear-fractional programming" of "Convex Optimization", Boyd and Vandenberghe https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an alternative answer.

Clearly, the problem is equivalent to
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{1-t}{t} & \leq & y \\
1-x           & =    & t \\
\end{array}
$$
which in turn is equivalent to
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{1}{t}  -1 & \leq & y \\
1-x             & =    & t \\
\end{array}
$$
This is clearly SOCP representable.

You should end up with
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
2 (1-x) (1+y) & \geq & \sqrt{2}^2 \\
1-x           & \geq & 0 \\
1+y           & \geq & 0 \\   
\end{array}
$$
which is the same as saying
$$
\left [
\begin{array}{c}
1-x \\
1+y \\
\sqrt{2} \\
\end{array}
\right ] \in RQ
$$
where RQ is a rotated quadratic cone as defined in the [Mosek modelling cook book](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer :)!

Answer (score 5):

You can model your constraint with the second order cone constraint $$\sqrt{2^2 + (x+y)^2} \le 2-x+y,$$ and a lower bound on $x$.

I found this by first multiplying both sides by $1-x$ to obtain $(1-x)y - x >= 0$. As we have a quadratic inequality with a convex feasible region, this hints to a quadratic or second order cone.

Rewriting this constraint gives $(1-x)(1+y) \ge 1$. Then I used Equation (7) in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(98)10032-0) to turn the constraint into a second order cone constraint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)!